# Spring Roo building the URL for a redirect - adds a :80 to the end of the URL

Tags: spring, jboss7.x

JBoss AS7.1.1.Final with Spring 3.1.0

We are using the Spring MVC framework generated by Spring Roo.

We are having a problem with redirect URLs.

The following redirect code is generated by Roo and resides in an AspectJ file. It is an example for a redirect to the 'show' page after a save of data on the 'create' page is complete.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String RequestorController.create(@Valid Requestor requestor, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
uiModel.addAttribute("requestor", requestor);
addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel);
return "requestors/create";
}
uiModel.asMap().clear();
requestor.persist();
return "redirect:/requestors/" + encodeUrlPathSegment(requestor.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
}
```

Here is our JBoss AS7 standalone.xml connector configuration:

```
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" socket-binding="ajp"/>
--> The URL Spring created was: ajp://servername/context/path
```

We tried this then:

```
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" socket-binding="ajp" scheme="https">
--> The URL Spring created was: https://servername:80/context/path (Notice how the :80 is appended. So this was ALMOST RIGHT.)
```

One more try, we added the redirect port as 443…

```
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" socket-binding="ajp" scheme="https" redirect-port="443">
--> Generated same thing, https://servername:80/context/path
```

What is going on with that :80 being appended?

Note: This worked fine in JBoss 4 and 5 likely because they are based on Tomcat connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up not to be the issue.

The issue was we had not set up the proxy-port and proxy-name attributes for the  element in JBoss AS7.

It was never a Spring Roo issue.